# What is the law of mass action?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

What is the [law of mass action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action)? This is a question which covers the area of chemistry. But unfortunately I don't know any sites which can clear my chemistry doubts. So kindly I request anyone to explain the law of mass action clearly. It will be a great help.

Comment: You may want to look at [chemistry.se] Stack Exchange. But I'm not familiar with their guidelines; they may consider this a bit too broad: you're asking for a complete description of a pretty intricate topic.

Comment: Is there something like that?

Comment: Yep, just follow the link in the comment! There are 170+ Stack Exchange sites, for a huge variety of things. Here it is again: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/. And the other sites are listed at https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions

Comment: Is there for bio too

Comment: It doesn't look as active as Physics SE, but https://biology.stackexchange.com/ exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of mass action is a statement about chemical equilibrium, concerning the densities of the various substances. Chemical equilibrium occurs when chemical substances can react together to make products, and the reaction can equally proceed in the reverse direction, and the conditions are such that a dynamic equilibrium is attained between forward and reverse processes, in thermal equilibrium. The law of mass action states that if the number densities (or, in a more precise statement, chemical activities) are raised to powers given by the reaction equation, and multiplied together, then the number obtained (called the reaction constant) depends only on the temperature and a combination of the standard chemical potentials of the reactants (you can find the precise equation in standard places such as wikipedia). Thus it gives information about the proportions of the various substances when equilibrium is attained. For more detail, see chapter 21 of "Thermodynamics, a complete undergraduate course" by Steane. (There is an element of self-promotion here since I am the author of that book, but this is exactly the sort of question I wanted to explain clearly when I wrote the book).